# how to make a button act according to a selected choice?

Tags: python, html, django, button

I have a django python project. In the main page I have a list of numbers and a search button. what I want is to make the button taking me to another page according to the choice selected from the list.
this is what I put in **urls.py**

```
url(r'^numero/(?P<numero>\d+)/$', 'plot_by_accountcode', name="plot_by_accountcode")
```

How should I declare the button in the templates file(.html)
e.g: I have this list of number `[12,13,14,15]` I select `13` and I click on search button I want it to take me to the page with the URL `http://IP/numero/13`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

1. Use a HTML `form` and retrieve the numbers in the view through GET parameters. But that means changing your URL pattern to not include the number.

   Pros: it is plain HTML, it is simple and straightforward.
   Cons: your URLs are not as nice as they were.
2. Use JavaScript to update the URL of your button when the user makes a selection.

   Pros: keep your nice URLs
   Cons: more complexity involved due to the need of using JavaScript.

Comment: the second solutions looks better I'll try it and then I'll tell you the result

Comment: All solutions tha tI found are with php and javascript can you suggest me how to realize the second solution?